# Why does `git mv` coredump when submodules are present?

Tags: git

I have a directory called `third_party`, which I wish to rename to `thirdParty`. Subdirectories of `third_party` have my `git submodules`, which is perhaps relevant. However, when I try to rename the directories, I get the following error:

```
$ git mv third_party/ thirdParty
git: builtin/mv.c:259: cmd_mv: Assertion `pos >= 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now `git status` show that I've deleted `third_party`, and `thirdParty` exists and has the desired data. Ok, so who cares if it core dumped, I'll restart `git` and try

```
$ git add thirdParty/
fatal: Unable to create 'basedir/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

Ok, just delete the lock and move on:

```
$ git add thirdParty/
$ git status
fatal: Could not chdir to '../../../../third_party/OpenBLAS': No such file or directory
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule thirdParty/OpenBLAS
```

(OpenBLAS is one of my git submodules.)
How can I get around this problem?

`git version 1.9.1`,

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "third_party/OpenBLAS"]
    path = third_party/OpenBLAS
    url = https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
    ignore = dirty
[submodule "third_party/boost"]
    path = third_party/boost
    url = https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
    ignore = dirty
[submodule "third_party/open-mpi"]
    path = third_party/open-mpi
    url = https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi-release.git
    ignore = dirty
```

Comment: If an assertion fails, that's a bug in the code.  Send a mail to git@vger.kernel.org with basically what you reported here.

Comment: There is a fix for out-of-bounds array access when moving git submodules that went in right after 1.9.1.  You might try with 2.0.0 or greater and see if that fixes things.